# Fit the background map to the container

Tags: leaflet

I am using Leaflet library to render states shapes. I am using OSM for background. I am setting `noWrap:true` for tile layer as I want to see only one background map covering entire world. Now I would like to make sure my background map is always fitting to the map div, without showing empty space.

Initial it fits to the layer bounds. But once user pans or zooms, we can see white space as the background image is no more available. If the background image is not available, I want to prevent, pan or zoom. How can I fit the background image completely to the div.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
            L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                // minZoom: 0,
                // maxZoom: 18,
                noWrap: true,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'mapbox.light'
            }).addTo(map);


            function zoomToFeature(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }
            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });
            }
            geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);
            map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &copy; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


        </script>`
```

Comment: Please find the fiddle, where I would like to restrict. URL: http://jsfiddle.net/m59cgoqn/ I would like to restrict panning or zooming beyond the world extents.

Answer (score 1):

[Calculate the zoom level at which the bounds are just larger than the map's visible area](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-getboundszoom), and then [ensure that the map can never zoom outer than that zoom level](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-setmaxzoom).

In other words:

```
map.setMinZoom( map.getBoundsZoom([[-180,85],[180,85]], true) );
```

You'll need to do this every time the size (in pixels) of the map's container changes, either by window resize or every time you're calling `invalidateSize()`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854681/leaflet-get-a-map-that-covers-the-full-screen/42855961#42855961